# An attribute list cannot appear here firebase-ios-sdk, Xcode 15.0 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have updated my Xcode to 15.0 and now its start giving me this error.

```
    ABSL_CONST_INIT extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited =
            Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
   // An attribute list cannot appear here
```

I have gone through [XCode 15.0 Release - firebase-ios-sdk bug: An attribute list cannot appear here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11840) issue on github but it does't provide support for swiftPackage manger.

[image: Xcode 15.0 Error]

Answer (score 12):

update Firebase to v10 or change the line to

```
extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited = Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
```

Comment: Is there any way to apply this change for the next time reinstall pod file like using react native patch for node_modules?

Comment: I have tried to update this line in package manager but I can make changes in these files ? @Asmaa

Comment: @cuongtd you can fork the pod and update the podfile with your git url

Comment: @QaziAmmar with SPM you can't make changes directly I think fork pod will solve the issue

Comment: worked for me, but is it the ideal way to make changes in the library files?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while integrating the Firebase in my iOS application project. What What I did to overcome the issue is that i updated the Firebase version to 10.

```
target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13
  pod 'CLTypingLabel' , '~> 0.4.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore' , '~> 10.0'
  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your package by going to project -> package dependencies and then selecting the package and update it to version 10 for Firebase [image]